# Thymeleaf code below closing a "th:replace" not working

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, replace, thymeleaf

I am working with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and I am stuck on this problem.

I have a file ** resources / templates / layout / layout.html **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <!-- <meta charset="UTF-8" /> -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta id="_csrf" name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
    <meta id="_csrf_header" name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="My site">
    <meta name="author" content="tercera colina">


    <title th:text="'Portal - ' + ${titulo}"></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" th:href="@{/assets/img/brand/favicon.png}" type="image/png">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700">
    <!-- Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/fonts/nucleo/css/nucleo.css}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css}" type="text/css">
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs4/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-select-bs4/css/select.bootstrap4.min.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css}">
    <!-- Argon CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/css/argon.min.css?v=1.2.0}" type="text/css">

    <!--OPCIONALES--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/jquery-ui.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/selectize.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css}" />    
    <!-- ESTILOS PARA RELOJ DE PLANILLA DE ASISTENCIA -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/reloj.css}" />

</head>

<body>

    <nav th:replace="layout/navs :: primary-nav"></nav>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="main-content" id="panel">

        <!-- Topnav -->
        <nav th:replace="layout/navs :: second-nav"></nav>

        <!-- Header -->
        <div th:fragment="header-form" class="header bg-primary pb-6">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="header-body">
                    <div class="row align-items-center py-4">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-7">
                            <h6 class="h2 text-white d-inline-block mb-0" th:text="${titulo}"></h6>
                            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="d-none d-md-inline-block ml-md-4">
                                <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-links breadcrumb-dark">
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#" th:text="'Listar ' + ${titulo}"></a></li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" th:text="'Nuevo / Editar ' + ${titulo}"></li>
                                </ol>
                            </nav>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer th:fragment="footer" class="footer pt-0">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-lg-between">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="copyright text-center  text-lg-left  text-muted">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <th:block th:fragment="layout-scripts">

        <!---------------------- CORE JS ---------------------->
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?v=3.4.1}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/jquery-scroll-lock/dist/jquery-scrollLock.min.js}"></script>

        <!---------------------- OPTIONAL JS ---------------------->
        <!--    selectize -->
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js}"></script>

        <!--    bootstrap-datepicker -->
        <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/jquery.spring-friendly.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/jquery.redirect.js}"></script>

        <!--    datatables -->
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs4/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-select/js/dataTables.select.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>

        <!--    autocomplete -->
        <script th:replace="layout/js/autocomplete_fecha_off :: javascript"></script>

        <!--    recaptcha -->
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

        <!---------------------- ARGON JS ---------------------->
        <script th:src="@{/assets/js/argon.js}"></script>

    </th:block>

</body>
</html>
```

And my template file where i implement fragments **resources/templates/estamento/listar.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="layout/layout :: head"></head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<body>

    <nav th:replace="layout/navs :: primary-nav"></nav>

    <div class="main-content" id="panel">

        <!-- Topnav -->
        <nav th:replace="layout/navs :: second-nav"></nav>

        <!-- Header -->
        <div th:replace="layout/layout :: header-form"></div>

        <!-- Page content -->
        <div class="container-fluid mt--6">
            <!-- Table -->
            <div class="row">               
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Datatable</h3>                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="py-4">
                            <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap w-100">
                                <thead class="thead-dark"></thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer th:replace="layout/layout :: footer" class="footer pt-0"></footer>

        </div>
    </div>

    <th:block th:include="layout/layout :: layout-scripts"></th>

    <div class="testing-class" th:text="HOLA"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I compile, the browser renders my file listar.html replacing the fragments successfully but the line:

```
<div class="testing-class" th:text="HOLA"></div>
```

Or any tag (except  and ) below:

```
<th:block th:include="layout/layout :: layout-scripts"></th>
```

it does not render.

What is my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the log for errors? Pages may partially render on error.

Comment: I got 1 error on a json file:

Expected name at 7:2

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
  },"files": [
    "./example.ts"
  ]
}

Line 7 is   **},"files": [** 

But i think it has nothing to do with my problem

Comment: Your `<th:block>` needs a closing `</th:block>` - but you only have `</th>`. You may want to validate your HTML for any other similar issues, just in case.

Comment: @andrewjames you are right. Thank you!!!